# How can I correct for the incorrect scaling my printer applies along the long axis of a page?

Tags: windows, printing, printer, calibration

This is a photo of a letter-size printout of a 4" x 4" text box printed from Microsoft Word on an HP Laserjet M602:

[image: printout]

When I measure the box along the short dimension of the page, the dimension is exactly 4":
[image: short dimension]

When I measure the box along the long dimension of the page, the dimension is approximately 1/64" less than 4":

[image: long dimension]

At the scale of 4" that's not a big problem.  But I need to print a template that is 48" long.  At that scale the error will be 3/16".

I have tried the following tests:

- Print the same box in landscape mode from Word.
- Print from Word to PDF first, then print the PDF in Foxit and Acrobat Pro.
- Create a 4" x 4" box in LibreCAD then both print directly to printer and export to PDF then print.
- Used each of the following drivers:

  - Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver
  - HP LaserJet A4/Letter Hardware-Copy PCL6 Class Driver
  - HP Universal Printing PS
- Printed from Windows 7 and Window 8.1

I have been careful to always keep resizing and scaling turned off.  The results have been perfectly consistent:

> The dimension of the box along the short side of the paper is always perfect.  The dimension of the box along the long side of the paper is always slightly short.

This seems to point to my printer being the culprit.

1. Is there a way to calibrate the printer to scale the dimensions of objects correctly?
2. Is there a way to scale that dimension in the Windows printing system to correct for the error in the printer?
3. Is there a way to scale that dimension in a PDF utility to correct for the error in the printer?

Comment: The first question is to determine whether this is a scaling or rounding problem.  If it's a scaling problem, the error will get proportionally bigger when you increase the size.  If it's a rounding error, it may always be off by a small amount, but that will hover around some value and not grow to a huge error.

Comment: It can also be a printer problem. 1/64" (0.5mm) is well within the printer specs.